Prevent resource drawable name obfuscation in release build apk
Since I've upgraded to

gradle-8.2
android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1
kotlin_version = "1.8.0"

But release apk has resources renamed which is undesired for some post processing of the apk
The issue does not appear for debug builds
I've tried setting minifyEnabled, shrinkResources but it didn't seem to work
debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.projectDefault
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PRODUCTION", "false"
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.projectDefault
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-gson.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PRODUCTION", "true"
        }

I also tried adding below in proguard-rules.pro, but no effect
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
And adding android.enableR8.fullMode = false is not working as well
How do I only keep code obfuscation and leave resources untouched
Here's the comparison
Debug build resources.arsc in apk analyser

Debug build res/drawables/ in apk analyser

Release build resources.arsc in apk analyser

Release build res/drawables/ in apk analyser


This question has been posted twice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78937427/150978 Please do not post question twice. If you want to add something to your question you can edit at any time.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68194183/150978

See also https://issuetracker.google.com/241955408

Seems this is related to android.enableResourceOptimizations=false flag which cant be disabled in gradle 8+
Related:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1655
https://jakewharton.com/smaller-apks-with-resource-optimization/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194183
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/options/BooleanOption.kt#190
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241955408
