How to disable new JVM resource compiler in Android Gradle plugin for release apk
As per Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.0 (March 2021) release notes
New JVM resource compiler
A new JVM resource compiler in Android Gradle plugin 4.2 tool replaces portions of the AAPT2 resource compiler, potentially improving build performance, especially on Windows machines. The new JVM resource compiler is enabled by default.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/aaptcompiler/src/main/java/com/android/aaptcompiler/ResourceCompiler.kt#61
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/issues/28

This is causing issues apk post processing as it renames the resources and dont know what else,
is it possible to turn this off? There's not much documentation around.
Here's the comparison
Debug build resources.arsc in apk analyser

Debug build res/drawables/ in apk analyser

Release build resources.arsc in apk analyser

Release build res/drawables/ in apk analyser


This question has been posted twice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78936639/150978 Please do not post question twice. If you want to add something to your question you can edit at any time.

I’m voting to close this question because it has already been posted some hours earlier with way more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78936639/150978

Seems this is related to android.enableResourceOptimizations=false flag which cant be disabled in gradle 8+
Related:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1655
https://jakewharton.com/smaller-apks-with-resource-optimization/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194183
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/options/BooleanOption.kt#190
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241955408
